# Difference between dielectric and insulators

Tags: electrical-resistance, material-science, dielectric, conductors

AS per my knowledge - dielectric are insulators which can be polarized in presence of external electric field.

Does that mean all Insulators are not dielectrics ? If yes then kindly share example of an insulator which is not dielectric.

Answer (score 2):

Dielectric implies nonmagnetic, so the best example of an insulator that isn't a dielectric I can think of is ferrite crystals like yttrium iron garnet, that show a magnetic response while having low or zero conductivity.

There are also ferroelectric materials that show a permanent polarization in response to an electric field, and these aren't considered dielectrics.

A word of warning though: the word dielectric is sometimes used in a much more general way. It's not necessarily incorrect to refer to poor conductors as dielectrics, and it's sensible to talk about the [dielectric properties of ferrites](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02744973). In this more general sense, any material that shows a response to an electric field (which is all of them) can be said to have dielectric properties.